# ActiveRecord query performance, performing a where after initial query has been executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this query:

```
absences = Absence.joins(:user).where('users.company_id = ?', @company.id).where('"from" <= ? and "to" >= ?', self.date, self.date).group('user_id').select('user_id, sum(hours) as hours')
```

This will return user_id's with a total of hours.

Now I need to to loop through all users of the company and do some calculations.

```
company.users.each do |user|
    tc = TimeCheck.find_or_initialize_by(:user_id => user.id, :date => self.date)
    tc.expected_hours = user.working_hours - absences.where('user_id = ?', user.id).first.hours
end
```

For performance reasons I want to have only one query to the absences table (the first one) and afterwards to look in memory for the correct user.  How do I best accomplish this?  I believe by default absences will be a ActiveRecord::Relation and not a result set.  Is there a command I can use to instruct activerecord to execute the query, and afterwards search in memory?

Or do I need to store absences as array or hash first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One SQL optimization you could make is:

change:

```
absences.where('user_id = ?', user.id).first.hours
```

to:

```
absences.detect { |u| u.user_id == user.id }.hours
```

Also, You might not need to loop through company.users. You may be able to loop through absences instead, depending on the business requirements.